# For UIView subclass, why initializer with empty argument is provided automatically if we override initializer with CGRect argument?

Tags: ios, swift

If I override `UIView` in the following way, I do not have initializer with empty argument.

```
class A: UIView {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
// Error. Initializer with empty argument not supported
let a = A()
```

---

However, if I override `UIView` in the following, I can get an initializer with empty argument?

```
class A: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}

// Why I can get a "free" init with empty argument?
let a = A()
```

At first glance, it seems that, for `UIView` subclass, an initializer with empty argument is provided automatically, if we override initializer with `CGRect` argument.

May I know how does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is stated very clearly in the [Swift Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID222):

> **Rule 1**
>
> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
> automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2**
>
> If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass
> designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per rule 1, or by
> providing a custom implementation as part of its definition—then it
> automatically inherits all of the superclass convenience initializers.

`init(frame:)` is the designated initialiser of `UIView`. By overriding them, your subclass inherit the convince initialiser that is parameterless.